# Inserting one XML file into another via for loop (XDocument)

Tags: c#, xml, list, linq-to-xml

This is something I haven't done before, so I might be doing it wrong to begin with, if I am, please let me know.

I created a root XML file with XDocument with:

```
public void SaveReceipt(List<ArticleFull> articles)
{
    XDocument receipt = new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
        new XElement("FiscalRecipet")
    );
    ...
}
```

And then with  a for loop tried to iterate through the `articles` List so I can build a receipt XML file.

```
for (int i = 0; i < articles.Count; i++)
{
    int quantity = 1;
    //This while loop just counts how many items are in a row
    while(!(i + 1 > articles.Count - 1))
    {
        if (articles[i].Id == articles[i + 1].Id)
        {
            quantity++;
            i++;
        }
        else break;
    }
    var enternode = new XElement("FiscalItem",
        new XElement("Name", articles[i].Name.ToString()),
        new XElement("Price", articles[i].Price.ToString()),
        new XElement("Quantity", quantity.ToString()),
        new XElement("TaxGroup", articles[i].TaxGroup)
    );
    //Code missing here...
}
```

Now, as stated above, I have absolutely no idea how to connect one the `receipt` variable to the `enternode` variable.

The end XML file *should* look something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FiscalRecipet>
    <FiscalItem>
        <Name>Coffee</Name>
        <Price>130.0</Price>
        <Quantity>1.0</Quantity>
        <TaxGroup>2</TaxGroup>
    </FiscalItem>
    <FiscalItem>
        <Name>Chocolate</Name>
        <Price>350.0</Price>
        <Quantity>2.0</Quantity>
        <TaxGroup>3</TaxGroup>
    </FiscalItem>
    <!-- etc... -->
</FiscalRecipet>
```

I tried searching for an answer by googling, but I didn't get very lucky, which is why I'm thinking I might be going in a wrong direction(?)

Comment: Perhaps you want to group-by `Id` first, instead of looping the entire list each time just to find matching ids?

Comment: Your comment about "This while loop just counts how many items are in a row" isn't really true - it's skipping entries in the main for loop, too...

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, you have a typo in your XML: Fiscal**Recipet**. Better fix it now, before it goes into production or anything. :-)

Comment: @Micke the XML is translated from my language (some of it, not that particular line), so it doesn't influence the code itself, but thanks for heads up! :)

Comment: @JonSkeet it's meant to skip them, yes :) but I like what you did in the answer more, though, never knew there was a 'preset' way to count items like that.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov it's meant to not really sort them, because some articles have addons (such as coffe could have suggar, but some other coffee could be normal (no suggar), so they have to be sorted separatelly.

Comment: Grouping isn't sorting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just need:

```
receipt.Root.Add(enternode);
```

In other words, adding the new element to the root element of the document.

There are likely to be rather simpler ways of doing all of this using LINQ, btw. I suspect you want something like:

```
var articlesById = articles
   .GroupBy(article => article.Id)
   .Select(g => new { Article = g.First(), Count = g.Count() });
XDocument receipt = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null),
    new XElement("FiscalRecipet",
        articlesById.Select(x => new XElement("FiscalItem",
            new XElement("Name", x.Article.Name),
            new XElement("Price", x.Article.Price),
            new XElement("Quantity", x.Count),
            new XElement("TaxGroup", x.Article.TaxGroup))
    )
);
```

That replaces your *whole* code.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the fiscal items as children of your fiscal receipt:

```
var fiscalReceipt = new XElement("FiscalRecipet");
var receipt = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null), fiscalReceipt);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var enternode = new XElement("FiscalItem",
        new XElement("Name", "foo"),
        new XElement("Price", i * 100),
        new XElement("Quantity", 1),
        new XElement("TaxGroup", "A"));

    fiscalReceipt.Add(enternode);
}

Console.WriteLine(receipt);
```

---

```
<FiscalRecipet>
  <FiscalItem>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Price>0</Price>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <TaxGroup>A</TaxGroup>
  </FiscalItem>
  <FiscalItem>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Price>100</Price>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <TaxGroup>A</TaxGroup>
  </FiscalItem>
  <FiscalItem>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Price>200</Price>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <TaxGroup>A</TaxGroup>
  </FiscalItem>
  <FiscalItem>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Price>300</Price>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <TaxGroup>A</TaxGroup>
  </FiscalItem>
  <FiscalItem>
    <Name>foo</Name>
    <Price>400</Price>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <TaxGroup>A</TaxGroup>
  </FiscalItem>
</FiscalRecipet>
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering that FiscalReceipt is the root, and FiscalItem is your element in it, what you can do is try method

```
root.Add(childElement);
```

This will add every FiscalItem as a child of FiscalReceipt.

MSDN link on same :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx